# Como puedo abrir e ir específicamente a un marcador de un PDF, ? en JavaFx

Tags: pdf, javafx

Se como encontrar el marcador y el numero de la pagina, así como abrir el documento, el problema es que ocupo que se abra y me lleve directamente hasta el marcador deseado.

```
@FXML
private void ayudaBasica() {
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Ayuda.pdf");
        List list = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
        for (Iterator i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            showBookmark((Map) i.next());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(FXML_Compra_MercanciaController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static void showBookmark(Map bookmark) {
    if (bookmark.get("Title").equals("CAMBIO DE CONTRASEÑA")) {
           System.out.println(bookmark.get("Page"));
    }
}
```

Pd. No puedo utilizar iText ni nada que no sea Open Source.

Saludos.